# Find out row number when two conditions met

Tags: r, data-cleaning

this question is related to R.

I have two data sets. Let say data sets A contains the following:
Dataset A:

```
Date      Market_Cap
2017-1-1  10
2017-1-2  30
2017-1-1  50
2017-1-5  100
2017-1-5  200
```

Another B contains the following:

```
Date      Thr_Market_Cap
2017-1-1  30
2017-1-2  20
2017-1-5  110
```

I then want to compare dataset A and dataset B. The criteria is when the Date is the same and threshold market cap in dataset B is greater than the market cap in dataset A. Then I want to delete the row of dataset A of that entry when these two criteria satisfied.

The result after querying in dataset A is:

```
Data      Market_Cap
2017-1-2  30
2017-1-5  200
2017-1-1  50
```

My dataset A contains 43,261,925 rows and dataset B contains 500 rows.

Please take a look at my code

A variable is dataset A and B variable is dataset B. Both are data frame.

```
A_row=dim(A)[1]

B_row=dim(B)[1]

cores <- parallel::detectCores()
cl<-makeSOCKcluster(cores) #change the  to your number of CPU cores
registerDoSNOW(cl)

pb <- txtProgressBar(min=1, max=A, style=3)
progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
opts <- list(progress=progress)

DEL <- foreach (i = 1:A_row, .options.snow=opts, 
.combine='rbind') %dopar% {
    for (j in 1:B_row){
        if (A$Date[i] == B$Date[j]){
            if(isTRUE(A$Market_Cap[i] < B$Thr_Market_Cap[j])){
                return(i)
            }   
        }
    }
}
close(pb)
```

DEL variable then contains list of all the rows number that satisfies the two criteria and then I can use it to delete the row in dataset A

```
Adj_A= A[,-c(DEL)]
```

I tried writing this code with parfor but it does not work, DEL always return NULL. If I write it in basic non-parallel computation for loop, it works flawlessly. But it takes ages due to the large file size...

Can some one comment on this code and I also want to know if there is any other way which uses build-in R function or dplyr to clean this data?

Much appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: Hi, it is in the question, i just edited.

Comment: In your example, why is 2017-1-1 removed, but not 2017-1-5?

Comment: sorry my bad... I just edited. So the rule is as long as thr_market_cap > market_cap  and date == date are satisfied then I want to pick this record out. All I could think of is by looping over all dataset and find the record. Is there any packages like data.table or dplyr that does the slightly complicated query like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join B to A, then filter. With `dplyr`:

```
left_join(A, B, by = "Date") %>% filter(Thr_Market_Cap <= Market_Cap)
```

If you want add `%>% select(-Thr_Market_Cap)` to get rid of the extra column.

You're data is quite large, if you use `data.table` instead this will probably be faster:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A, key = "Date")
setDT(B, key = "Date")

A = B[A, on = "Date"][Thr_Market_Cap <= Market_Cap, ]
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor. So the package will do this? e.g. for the first entry on dataset A, it will compare every entry in dataset B and will stop if the condition satisfied? Thanks

Comment: ahhh this method is so smart!! So I believe what it does is first sort according to date and joint both dataset together. So every entry I can compare dataset B's Thr_Market_Cap on the same date with dataset A's Market_Cap. Many thanks Gregor!!